# QCamera - Tilt/Pan Rotation induces Roll Rotation

Tags: c++, qt

I can't understand why it's doing that...

Referencing to [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qcamera.html), I use `tilt(float)` and `pan(float)` to do the job.

The camera code :

```
#include "camera.h"

#define SLOW_FACTOR 0.1

Camera::Camera() : QCamera() {
    //Projection
    setFieldOfView(45.0);
    setAspectRatio(1.0);
    setNearPlane(1.0);
    setFarPlane(100.0);

    //View
    setPosition(QVector3D(0,0,10));
    setViewCenter(QVector3D(0,0,0));
}

void Camera::orientate(int xRotate, int yRotate) {
    pan(xRotate * SLOW_FACTOR);
    tilt(yRotate * SLOW_FACTOR);
}

void Camera::move(QVector3D vec) {
    translate(vec);
}

QMatrix4x4 Camera::getModelView(QMatrix4x4 model) {
    return projectionMatrix() * viewMatrix() * model;
}
```

[image: Tilt/Pan/Roll]

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: there it is, sorry